# What are the top crypto-currencies based on funding?

Tags: altcoin

What are some of the top crypto currencies that received outside funding? Would be great if there was a list of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Bitshares - 500,000 USD from investors + 5625 BTC in donations (via BTS AGS)
- Digibyte - 250,000 USD from investors
- Ethereum - 31,531 BTC from presale
- Factom - 2287 BTC from presale
- GetGems - 2633 BTC from presale
- MaidSafe - around 12,200 in BTC from presale
- Mastercoin (Omni) - around 4700 BTC from presale
- NEM - around 63 BTC from presale
- Neucoin - 2.25M USD from Investors + around 4000 BTC from Neucoin presale.
- NXT - around 21 BTC from presale
- Ripple - Over 30M USD from VC's
- Stellar - 3M USD from Stripe
- Storj - 910 BTC from presale
- SuperNet - 5737 BTC from presale ~ part the the NXT platform asset
- Swarm - 1200 BTC from presale
- ViaCoin - 610 BTC from presale
- Ziftr - 3700 BTC from presale

Taken from: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1045967.0

**Highest funding:** Ethereum & Ripple

**Lowest funding:** NXT -- but they seem to have the most progress compared to every coin out there so far from this research as of 2015-Jun.

Conclusion, its not funding or even a good team, but something else in play that causes good progress in one of these funded coins.